# GroupBy after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following DTO:

```
class Permission
{
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    public string? AccountId { get; set; }
    public string? GroupId { get; set; }
}

var permissions = new List<Permission>()
{
    new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = "1", GroupId = null },
    new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = "2", GroupId = null },
    new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = null, GroupId = "1" },
    new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:write", AccountId = "2", GroupId = null },
    new(){ ObjectId = "2", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = "1", GroupId = null },
};
```

I want the following outcome:

```
{[
    "1": {
        "read": {
            "accounts": ["1", "2"],
            "groups": ["1", "2", "3"]
        },
        "write": {
            "accounts": ["1", "2"],
            "groups": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }
  }
]}
```

Basically an array of objects of `Permission`, grouped by their `ObjectId` property, and then grouped by each `Scope` that contains an array of the `AccountId` or `GroupId` properties.

Each `Permission` can have the same `ObjectId` but different `Scope`, `AccountId` and `GroupId`.

I tried to use `GroupBy` but that gives me an `IGrouping` and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: first of all Do you understand how `Enumerable.GroupBy` works? there is no code which shows how did you tried to use... second your json is no valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 1):

You need more than just nested group bys. In your output JSON you have keys as property names. You also need to use `ToDictionary` to convert values into property keys.

```cs
var permissions = new List<Permission>()
        {
            new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = "1", GroupId = null },
            new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = "2", GroupId = null },
            new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = null, GroupId = "1" },
            new(){ ObjectId = "1", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:write", AccountId = "2", GroupId = null },
            new(){ ObjectId = "2", ObjectType = "link", Scope = "link:read", AccountId = "1", GroupId = null },
        };
        var result = permissions.GroupBy(r=> r.ObjectId).Select(r=> new {
            r.Key,
            InnerGroups = r.GroupBy(q=> q.Scope.Replace("link:","")).Select(q=> new {
                Scope = q.Key,
                Accounts =  q.Where(z=> z.AccountId != null).Select(z=> z.AccountId).ToArray(),
                Groups = q.Where(z=> z.GroupId != null).Select(z=> z.GroupId).ToArray()
            })
        })
            .ToDictionary(r=> r.Key,r=> r.InnerGroups.ToDictionary(q=> q.Scope,q=> new {q.Accounts,q.Groups}));
        
        var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result,new JsonSerializerOptions{ WriteIndented=true });
```

Here is the output :

```json
 {
  "1": {
    "read": {
      "Accounts": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "Groups": [
        "1"
      ]
    },
    "write": {
      "Accounts": [
        "2"
      ],
      "Groups": []
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "read": {
      "Accounts": [
        "1"
      ],
      "Groups": []
    }
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AopQO9)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use nested `GroupBy` to achieve that and then convert the result to the dictionaries:

```
var result = permissions
    .GroupBy(p => p.ObjectId)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.GroupBy(g => g.Scope)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => new
    {
        accounts = g.Select(per => per.AccountId).Distinct().ToList(),
        groups = g.Select(per => per.GroupId).Distinct().ToList()
    }));
```